# Transferring multiple files across LAN using c# with increased performance

Tags: c#, file, ftp

We have some existing C# .NET 2.0 code which copies files from a client PC to a publicly shared folder on a remote server using the File.Copy command. Sometimes this might be a single file. Sometimes hundreds of files in a batch.

We also have some similar code which copies files using FTP to a secured folder.

Both of these codes loop over each file and are fairly slow.

I am wondering what is the recommended ways I can improve the standard copy and the FTP copy. I am happy to consider commercial solutions.

Thanks for any advice with this.

Comment: There might be some things you can do if you're not restricted to .NET 2.0, but in the end you're talking about file I/O so by its nature its expensive.

Comment: Not sure you'll improve on `File.Copy`. One way to go would be to still use your existing methods but try to reduce the data you're sending - i.e. zip/compress the files. Maybe combine them too.

Comment: For FTP, you can greatly enhance the speed if you combine all files into a single dummy zip file. If your server is fast enough, you could also compress the file, but combining all the files into a single container makes you get rid of a lot of overhead.